# Passing parameters to TestNG run - Gradle

Tags: java, spring, testng, gradle

I have some tests in TestNG and I use Gradle to run them. I have some properties in spring beans that I want to select at runtime.

So, for select this different beans I want to pass string parameters to the useTestNG invocation. My build.gradle looks as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'java'
dependencies {
  compile fileTree(dir: 'lib', include: '*.jar')
}
test {  
    useTestNG()
}
```

The parameters would be like "bean1", "bean2",... and in the Java code I'll select what bean use.

```
    ApplicationContext context = new FileSystemXmlApplicationContext("**/pathToXML.xml");       
    Locators obj = (Locators) context.getBean("bean1");
```

If this isn't a good way to solve this problem and a different approach is better I'll be thankfully to know it

Answer (score 1):

You can pass all the system properties like so:

```
test {
    systemProperties System.getProperties()
    useTestNG()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off including the passing og the parameters to the application code from testng itself. 
If you pass in different parameters from gradle you will  prevent easy and fast execution of the unit tests from other places, like an IDE like Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass system properties in the test task as follows:

```
test{
    systemProperty 'bean1', 'com.foo.Bar'
    useTestNG()
}
```

In you Java code you can access it with `System.getProperty("bean1");`